# Getting Wordpress To Work

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

I am trying to get an Old Wordpress site up and running.

Here is what I have:

- WAMP Server: everything is running, and up to date
- Old Wordpress Site Folders
- Old Wordpress Site Database

I have uploaded the old database to the newly installed phpmyadmin, and I have linked the database with the Wordpress Site Folders in the wp-config.php.

Everything is working the way it is supposed to EXCEPT the old Wordpress sites cannot be edited with wordpress.

I have also tried linking a new wordpress site with the old wordpress database and when I do that I get the wordpress install page. Even though wordpress is already installed.

I have also tried importing the old wordpress site to the new wordpress site, but a screen comes up saying "unexpected error, please visit the support forums" Which I did, but nothing was any use to me.

**So, how do I get my old wordpress site to work with my newly installed wordpress?**

*Side Note: I did go here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress and I followed the instructions, but my Old Site is still not working properly.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by you cannot edit the sites in Wordpress? What exactly are you trying to do and what result are you getting?

Comment: @Sirago I'm sorry. I will try to clarify. When I try to see the Old Site, it works, except it only contains text (it looks like a basic HTML file), and does not look like it used to. I also cannot make edits with the old site as I am able to do with newer sites I have created with my newly installed wordpress.

Comment: Only contains text, like it's missing its styling? CSS?

Comment: @Sirago yes, like its missing its styling. However I have all of the CSS files, everything is there. My main concern is not being able to make edits to the site. Am I missing a permission?

Comment: When loading the page, open your browser console (F12) and look for any 404 errors. If your CSS isn't displaying, I wonder what else is not connecting..

Comment: @Sirago I have lot's of CSS errors. Like `Error is parsing value for 'filter'. Deceleration dropped.` There are also a lot of `Unknown property` as well. However I do not have any 404 errors. I am assuming these errors stem from the fact the this site is not working with wordpress

Comment: Is the entire site (theme/template) missing its styling, or just the content (page/blog post)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the original files and original database, that is the best approach to get it up and running. If you want to upgrade WordPress, first get it working with the old version, then do in-place upgrades (after backing up, of course). Some of the original plugins may not be compatible, though, so be mindful of that.

If you're using a different domain name (e.g., `localhost` instead of `old.domain.com`) then consider the steps given in [Wordpress's guide to Changing the site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL). It would also be worth perusing [Moving Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).

Comment: @Ivmisooners I would love if it was a simple fix, that I am not seeing. What do you mean about file permissions?

Comment: I was focusing on this statement: "**Everything is working** the way it is supposed to **EXCEPT the old Wordpress sites cannot be edited with wordpress.**" Did you get an error? Were changes simply ignored? Did it update partially? What symptoms are you seeing? I mentioned file permissions as an example of a basic issue that can cause problems: if WP is trying to write files to disk and cannot, you would see negative side affects.

Comment: @Ivimisooners No I didn't get an error, not really. Not on the site. But the old sites do not work correctly with the wp-admin folder. When I try localhost\oldsite\wp-login I get a 403 error. But no errors come up with localhost\oldsite.  When I pull up developer tools for the old site I get a 403 errors, and its trying to access files not on my domain. But the new wordpress site works fine. You can edit it. Did that clarify?

Comment: Ahh, 403s -- we can work with that! I updated my answer with references on how to change the URL of a wordpress site. Wordpress is particular about having the same dir structure and domain name, so you have to explicitly tell it if something has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need to be sure that site url and home page url is correct in your old database if not edit it .

check if you have errors in loading css files in firebug and if so check the urls used to locate the css files.

try to rename the theme directory to force WordPress to use the default theme, this will help if the errors is theme related.

**try to provide more details about the following:**

- can you access site pages and if there any errors .
- check wp-config.php and set debug to true and reload to see if there is any
  php errors.
- can you access admin area with or without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a while back, but what I ended up doing was using wordpress's link to a phpscript that changes the database. To get it to work I replaced what the database was pointing to at the old wordpress site which was a different computer than mine and I pointed everything back to localhost.

A link to the php script I used can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

*side note: DELETE the script when you are done.